# Como consumo un api solo usando java y convierto el json obtenido en un array de objetos

Tags: java, array, json, api

Quiero consumir esta api y recorrer los datos dentro de un jsp, pero no logro recuperar los datos de manera adecuada para recorrerlos dentro de un ciclo en el jsp ya que solo logro consumirlos como string y no he logrado convertirlos a un array de objetos de java

```
// 20220401221251
// http://localhost:8080/api/providers

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Del valle"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Dos Pinos"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mu"
  }
]
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Fetch {
    String url;

    public Fetch(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String fetchApi() throws IOException {
        URL jsonpath = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/providers");
        URLConnection urlcon = jsonpath.openConnection();
        BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlcon.getInputStream()));

        String json = buffread.readLine();
        buffread.close();

        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado usar `jackson`  para trabajar con `json`s?

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas prueba a usar la siguiente función despues de obtener el string:

```
ArrayList<String> jsonStringToArray(String jsonString) throws JSONException {

ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    stringArray.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
}

return stringArray;
}
```

Asegurate de tener el paquete org.json.